# Export oracle database to sql file?

Tags: oracle, backup

I have a database that is in oracle 8i and i want to export the entire database of a user to a .sql file and the import it to another system that has oracle 10g installed on it.

Comment: i dont know about exporting am new to this please guide me...

Comment: To export read this: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/A87860_01/doc/server.817/a76955/ch01.htm

Comment: can i have the entire database for a user into a single .sql file

Comment: i mean to say all tables and sequences and all

Comment: DId you literally want a SQL file or are you ok with the Oracle-specific dump (which is the usual solution and the answer suggests)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To export your database, you must use the 8i exp utility:

```
exp full=y compress=N userid=system/system_pw file=dumpfilename.dmp log=explog.txt
```

To import your database, you must use the 10g imp utility:

```
imp full=y file=dumpfilename.dmp userid=system/system_pw log=implog.txt
```

The 10g imp utility is backward compatible with previous releases, so you should be able to export using the 8i exp utility and import with the 10g imp. Both utilities have a "help=y" parameter that will display a list of parameters you can specify. There are quite a few; for the most part the defaults are fine. Depending on the size of your database, this could take a while.

Creating a single SQL file is not as easy as it may seem at first, due to circular dependencies of certain objects. Plus, it's not as efficient to create or execute - exp/imp is far more so. If your goal is simply to move the database to a new version of Oracle, exp/imp is the simplest way to go.

Some documents to help you out: [orafaq.com;](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Import_Export_FAQ) [Oracle 8i Utilities (oracle.com)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/A87861_01/NT817EE/server.817/a86632/migeximp.htm); [Oracle 10g utilities (oracle.com)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/exp_imp.htm).

Comment: exp/imp is my preferred method to do anything like this.  Its robust, fairly quick, very simple, always works, can be used to migrate across OS, 16-32bit or 32-64bit, etc, etc.  Having done this a number of times I can assure you this will achieve your goals.