# How can I integrate data and program into single executable file?

Tags: java, database, executable

Recently I created a project that manages details of students living in hostel and stores all the details regarding the fees paid by them.

**I'm using Netbeans IDE to provide required GUI and ORACLE10g for the database support.**
I want to know how can make these two components into one single executable file.
For example right now, when I export my program from one system to another I have to create (only one time though) DATABASE from scratch in new system and then I have to repeat all the queries to have same data as original system.
Are there any other way to accomplish above task automatically (i.e. from a executable file)?
I'm using Windows7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Oracle will allow you to bundle Oracle database and your program without going through their installer and accepting their license.

You could change your application in a way that enables you to configure an already installed Oracle instance silently, but the installation of Oracle will stay a separate task.

If an instance of Oracle already exists you have two choices, one of them is less likely to work in large-scale companies (at least those I know).
Your application can check the database if the tables it needs already exists (but even for this you need to know the name of the server, the schema and username and password to connect to the database).
If the tables don't exist you can create tables and indexes from inside your program. But this means that the user your application takes to connect needs to have rather high privileges. Many companies don't grant such permissions because they are not necessary during the rest of the applications lifetime.
Another approach is to create DDL scripts, basically they trigger the same CREATE TABLE / INDEX statements your application would but they are there to be run by a database administrator.

If you really want to bundle application and database including a schema you should go for something that is embeddable. There are plenty of database systems for Java, you will find them here on stackoverflow (H2, Derby, ...)
Otherwise you will never be able to have a "plug and play" experience with your application because there are more or less steps needed to get it set up correctly.

Turning your application into a single executable is then the task of programs like Install4J, here can find many similar products on - you guessed it - on stackoverflow too.

Comment: can you point out how I can change my application that will allow me to configure an already installed Oracle. Separate installation of ORACLE is Okay, but I don't want to create all the tables and insert data again.

Answer (score 0):

You should create *.sql file template that will create the database and all tables for you in a newly deployed ORACLE10g.

On a new machine with Oracle database, you will just run import that template SQL file which will automatically create all tables.

The SQL file may look like (syntax may differ from ORACLE10g dialect):

```
--
-- codes
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `codes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` tinytext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idmeteor`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;

--
-- Dump of `codes`
--

INSERT INTO `codes` (`id`, `description`) VALUES
(1, 'X'),
(2, 'Y'),
(3, 'Z'),
....
(9, 'W');
```

Another way is to use exporting/importing tools for Oracle database that can be found at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138815/export-oracle-database-to-sql-file) (export/import existing database not in SQL format).